# Validate the input dates

Tags: java, android

Friends I am having a String that contains date-record

```
10-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @$12-Oct-2012 @12-Oct-2012 @$12-Sept-2012 13:50@12-Oct-2012 13:50@$12-Feb-2012 13:50@12-Oct-2012 13:50@$
```

representing a record in pairs showing the arrival & dept date. I need to validate this date in such a way that the if the date that is to be entered lies in already existing peroid,then that date must not be added.

Comment: See [Date#after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after(java.util.Date)) and [Date#Before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for parsing your String into Date

Comment: Also, see [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), and enjoy playing with Dates.

Comment: When you say, 'if the date that is to be entered lies in an already prexisting period', do you mean when the [i]range[\i] to be entered already intersects with some range, to not add it? Or do you just want the start dates to not be in another date range?

Comment: IF the date lies in the range,record must not be added, but the part which lies in unmodified range must be added. Hope I made your doubt clear

Comment: Not really. Say I have the date range 1/1/1 to 1/4/1 (MM/DD/YY), and the date set 1/7/1 to 1/10/1 added. If I were to decide how to add the date set 1/5/1 to 1/5/10, do I 1) ignore it or 2) add dates 1/5 and 1/6? Also, ignoring the previous situation, say I only have the date range 1/10/1 to 1/12/1 added, and I'm trying to decide whether to add 1/1/1 to 1/1/11 to this. Do I ignore it or add the dates 1/1 to 1/9.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "@" to split dates and then use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert Strings in to Date. Sore the Date in a `ArrayList` and then check check it the ArrayList already contans the Date.

However, if this is ALL you need you might not even need to convert String to Date, why not just split strings and add in an ArrayList and then compare them?

I would really appreciate if I could see more of your code.

Comment: I thought the same as you first (use a Set actually) but s/he needs to exclude Dates that fall in a range between two dates, so String comparisons will be strange to cover a range.